# doGet() Missing ')' in parenthetical

Tags: html, google-apps-script

```
[16-09-16 14:10:03:391 CDT] Starting execution
[16-09-16 14:10:03:398 CDT] HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile([Index]) [0.001 seconds]
[16-09-16 14:10:03:399 CDT] Function.apply([[]]) [0 seconds]
[16-09-16 14:10:03:401 CDT] Execution failed: SyntaxError: Missing ) in parenthetical. (line 2, file "Code") [0.004 seconds total runtime]
```

That is the execution transcript. I have a few other google sites that run similar scripts without issue. In fact most of the Code.gs is the same, just subtle differences in the data being called. My issue appears to be in the doGet function for this specific apps script project.

Essentially I am building an intranet for my company within google sites and they like to keep tons of stuff in spreadsheets so I am building the webpages from that data. 
Code.gs~~~~

```
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function getMisc(){
   return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1sORbt2nn3a5-NV_aR3CmmGCwYac-9ASmNrRySmOlBC4')
      .getSheetByName("MiscSuppliers")
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}
```

Index.html~~~~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <base target="_top">
     <style>
        <?!= include('StyleSheet'); ?>
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>

     <table class="table2">
        <? var info = getInfo() ?>
        <? var files = getInfo() ?>
        <? var login = getInfo() ?>
        <tr>
           <td>
               <? for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) { ?> 
               <?= info[i][0] ?>
               <? } ?>
           </td>
           <td>
               <?= files[0][0] ?>
           </td>
           <td>
               <? for (var i = 0; i < login.length; i++) ?>
               <?= login[i][0] ?>
      <? } ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

doGets for all my code are identical. Any offshoot reason this one is not working? Apologies for poor editing or poorly asked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Index.html** file you're missing the opening bracket at this line:

```
<? for (var i = 0; i < login.length; i++) ?>
```

It should be:

```
<? for (var i = 0; i < login.length; i++) { ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, dumb error on my part. Was going down the rabbit hole for all potential issues. Appreciate the help ocordova.